# What should come after 'us', 'is' or 'are'?

Tags: grammar

Should it be "every single one of us is" or "every single one of us are"? seeing as 'us' is a plural term, should the word 'are' come afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

No.

The "is" refers to "every single **one**" (as in: every single person), and that's singular.

Comment: +1. *One is*. *Every*, *single*, and *of us* are only descriptions, which do not change the conjugation.